# How can I use GetString() on a user inputted string?(RapidJson)

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I just want to be able to have the user input a string that is the name of a specific object and then have GetString() return its string. This a part of the JSON file I'm using...

```
"Rogue Refiner": {
  "name": "Rogue Refiner",
  "power": "3",
  "toughness": "2"
},
```

This is how I return the specific values I want...

```
Document d;
d.Parse(data.c_str());
d["Rogue Refiner"]["name"].GetString());
```

I want to be able to be able to have the user input a string in the command prompt because the JSON file has thousands of objects like "Rogue Refiner". I assumed that this would work...

```
Document d;
d.Parse(data.c_str());

std::string stringName;
std::cin >> stringName;
d[stringName]["name"].GetString());
```

but it won't work. The error says "no operator "[]" matches these operands". So if anyone knows how I can have the users input the name of the objects that they want to find that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operator[]` for a `Document` takes a `const char *`. Use `d[stringName.c_str()]["name"].GetString());` instead.

Comment: So that format works perfectly when I do string stringName = "Rogue Refiner"; It accesses the JSON file and pulls up all the values. However, when I try to input Rogue Refiner using cin it throws an exception on line 1137 of document.h. Do you know why it is doing this?

Comment: Not without context and/or code, I'd advise you to open another question.

Comment: I actually found another post on here saying to use the getline function and that worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!